# How do I do this Play Store transition animation with a collapsing toolbar?

Tags: android, android-animation

I'm sorry if this has already been answered.

I want to do this animation: [Link](https://9to5google.files.wordpress.com/2015/05/transition.gif)

Comment: It's called the Circular Reveal and it works for 4.0+ (https://github.com/ozodrukh/CircularReveal)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Android's Shared Element transition.

For example you can look here
[shared element transition](https://android.jlelse.eu/easy-android-shared-element-transition-ac36952a4a4#.ahouqzxif)

Comment: I'm currently using shared element transition. It just goes from a rectangular ImageView to another rectangular ImageView, there is no circular reveal effect.

Comment: look at the example above